# select statement in php with restriction

Tags: php, html, mysql

i don't know the proper title i need. i'm doing a document tracking system using php

i don't know how to solve this problem. i don't have any idea. so i can't search because i don't know the keyword to use.

the problem how will the system knows the first person the sign the document. before the next signatory can sign the document

example. i have document 1. the document 1 is need to be signed by 3 signatory.

the 3 signatory are:
president, vice president and dean.

the first person who need to sign the document is the dean, then the vice president, and finally the president

what i want is the document that need to be signed by the other signatory is visible only when the first signatory signed the document

example scenario. after the dean signed the document. then it will become visible in the system that the vice president need to sign that document. and after the vice president signed the document. then the system will prompt the president to sign that document.

please give me some idea how it is done. thank you. sorry for my bad english

Comment: You maywant to have a look at the [tour]. Your question, as it is now, will most likely be closed. Please show some kind of effort of solving your own problem before asking here. As of now, it is not even clear wether you are planning to use the technology you tagged.

Comment: Use a text (or integer) field on the document to denote state, and only show document `where state='signed by dean'` to the vice president?

Answer (score 0):

You have entity "Document". Add to entity property SignStatus. By default SignStatus = 'not_signed'.

after the dean signed the document Document->SignStatus = 'dean_signed';

after the vicepresenent signed the document Document->SignStatus = 'vice_pres_signed';

after the president signed the document Document->SignStatus = 'pres_signed';

Comment: thank you for the idea sir. ill post again if this works

Answer (score 0):

You could use a database to store informations about the documents.

But to do so you should have basic knowledge of databases.

Maybe start by reading the php manual?

Try some howtos to, like:

create a database,
create a table,
insert something in a table,
read something from a table ...with php

Then search for howtos about database design...

For me your question reads like you have no programming experience at all.
Before you ask questions you should read! At least a couple months...

Comment: i know how to program in php sir. i know some basic stuff, like database. but the problem is i don't know how to solve the problem because i don't have any idea what are the things i need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple scheme that works for the problem described. Assuming you have a table where you list the documents, keep flags for every signature: `deanSigned`, `vicePresidentSigned`, and `presidentSigned`. Where the default value is zero and you set the flag to 1 once the person signed. Then you can select the appropriate documents as follows:

For the dean:

```
SELECT id 
FROM documents
WHERE deanSigned = 0;
```

For the vice president:

```
SELECT id
FROM documents 
WHERE deanSigned = 1 
  AND vicePresidentSigned = 0;
```

For the president:

```
SELECT id 
FROM documents 
WHERE deanSigned = 1 
  AND vicePresidentSigned = 1
  AND presidentSigned = 0;
```

I would advise against using a single field for the three signatures. It might also be sensible to think about having a separate `signatory` table that allows for a more flexible approach.

Comment: No good idea, imagine that document are this way. dean -> main dean -> general dean -> vice director -> director of section -> main director?

Comment: You can create an additional table "DocumentWay"  Id | DocumentId | SignatorID | SignType (giving from Signator->SignType) | SIgnDate .  That give you more flexibility and document sign history

Comment: Yeah having a signatory log would be a nice feature. If you want to do extended requirements gathering you're welcome to get in touch with Audrey :-)